# Conditional first passage of a BM

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Given a Brownian Motion $W_t$ I am interested to know if the following makes sense.

Write $\tau=\inf\{t:W_t<x\}$ as the first passage time which has a known probability $\mathbb{P}[\tau\leq t]$.

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\mathbb{P}[\tau\leq t]}{\mathbb{P}[\tau> t-\epsilon]}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1-\mathbb{P}[\tau>t]}{\mathbb{P}[\tau> t-\epsilon]}=\frac{1-\mathbb{P}[\tau>t]}{\mathbb{P}[\tau> t]}$$

Comment: The limit in the denominator certainly is true because the density of exiting is continuous.  However, I presume you would like to know that without first knowing the density.  That I would like to see proven as well.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's just sufficient to observe CDFs are right continuous.

Comment: that's what I think as well, but need a confirmation on this.

Comment: Actually the result holds because the CDF of $\tau$ is LEFT continuous, and this is true because the distribution of $\tau$ has no atom, that is, $P(\tau=t)=0$ for every $t>0$. (Otherwise, the limit of the ratio would be $(1-P(\tau>t))/P(\tau\geqslant t)$ instead of $(1-P(\tau>t))/P(\tau>t)$.)